# shp to dgn microstation export file error

Tags: qgis, shapefile, dgn

I want to export my shapefile into microstation dgn using qgis. But when I do click right on layer and "save as" this message error shows: Export to vector file failed. OGR ORIGIN is not a valid 2d or 3d tuple. Separate tuple values with comma.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: what value did you enter in --> datasource options -> ORGIN? I think you shoud better use QGIS-Export to DXF or Microstation Shapeimport. GDAL only support DGN V7.

Comment: V8 driver is available http://www.gdal.org/drv_dgn.html.